# Speakers connected on rear audio panel don't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound

I am new to linux, I just installed it and speakers don't work and they are connected on my back panel. But headphones connected on front panel are working properly. I didn't install any software or drivers for sound, I just checked installing 3rd party software while installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

I already saw the solution with disabling auto-mute in AlsaMixer but when I opened it it showed me nothing except small rectangle with `<S/PDIF>` below it. So I gave up on that solution. So if anybody else can't find auto-mute in AlsaMixer this is the steps:

1. type: `alsamixer` (small caps) in terminal
2. press f6 to select sound card (before I had `HDA ATI HDMI` selected)
3. change sound card to `HD-Audio Generic`
4. Navigate using left and right arrow buttons to find `<auto-mute>` in the bottom of the window and press up or down to change it from enabled to disabled.

That did it for me.

Comment: wow thank you so much & what an incredibly dumb default setting!

Comment: My hero. Thanks a bunch!! Working on Ubuntu V20.04

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set default audio output in settings. Front and rear are different devices in simple words.
2. Did you connected audio to front and rear panel before boot? That also can matters sometimes. That depends on hardware and drivers, audio device may be not detected when nothing is plugged in.

Comment: In sound settings I got "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" and "Headphones" under "Play sound through" , so only headphones are recognized by system. Nothing changes when I pull out and in rear audio jack. 

I don't exactly understand the second part of the answer. I had the rear jack plugged in whole time before, during and after installation. But both headphones and speakers work fine in windows 7.

Comment: I have met this problem in 16.04 few days ago,  device not detected when nothing is plugged in and turned on. If this is not case of your problem I don't known solution. May be.. may be, try to connect your headphones to rear panel and see what happens.